# AWS CDK - update existing lambda environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I would love to be able to update an existing lambda function via AWS CDK. I need to update the environment variable configuration. From what I can see this is not possible, is there something workable to make this happen?

I am using code like this to import the lambda:

```
    const importedLambdaFromArn = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(
      this,
      'external-lambda-from-arn',
      {
        functionArn: 'my-arn',
        role: importedRole,
      }
    );
```

For now, I have to manually alter a cloudformation template. Updating directly in cdk would be much nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, although you should read @Allan_Chua's answer before actually doing it. Lambda's [UpdateFunctionConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html) API can modify a deployed function's environment variables. The CDK's [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) construct lets us call that API during stack deployment.<sup>*</sup>

Let's say you want to set `TABLE_NAME` on a previously deployed lambda to the value of a DynamoDB table's name:

```js
// MyStack.ts

const existingFunc = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(this, 'ImportedFunction', arn);

const table = new dynamo.Table(this, 'DemoTable', {
  partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: dynamo.AttributeType.STRING },
});

new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'UpdateEnvVar', {
  onCreate: {
    service: 'Lambda',
    action: 'updateFunctionConfiguration',
    parameters: {
      FunctionName: existingFunc.functionArn,
      Environment: {
        Variables: {
          TABLE_NAME: table.tableName,
        },
      },
    },
    physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of('DemoTable'),
  },
  policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
    resources: [existingFunc.functionArn],
  }),
});
```

Under the hood, the [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) creates a lambda that makes the `UpdateFunctionConfiguration` call using the JS SDK when the stack is created. There are also `onUpdate` and `onDelete` cases to handle.

---

* Again, whether this is a [good idea or not](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps) depends on the use case. You could always call `UpdateFunctionConfiguration` without the CDK.

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks for the solution! I am not sure if this will work with aws amplify deployments and the resulting lambdas does seem tricky. I will likely mark this accepted since it seems like the only real solution at the moment.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question.  The qustion asks about updating an environment variable on an existing Lambda using CDK and this answer is talking about DynamoDB...

Comment: @ccu  The table name is an _example_ of an env var.  Use `MY_ENV_VAR: "Foo"` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `CDK` is to enable AWS customers to have the capability to automatically `provision` resources. If we're attempting to update settings of pre-existing resources that were managed by other CloudFormation stacks, it is better to update the variable on its parent CloudFormation template instead of CDK. This provides the following advantages on your side:

- There's a single source of truth of what the variable should look like
- There's no tug o war between the CDK and CloudFormation template whenever an update is being pushed from these sources.
- Otherwise, since this is a compute layer, just get rid of the lambda function from CloudFormation and start full CDK usage altogether bro!

Hope this advise helps

Comment: thanks for the advice. I do have a bit of lock-in with aws amplify. Thankfully amplify is allowing cdk resources to be added, however adding functions via cdk is not possible so in order to keep deployments with amplify I am trying to find these workarounds. I will likely manually update the CF templates for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Amplify, the accepted answer will not work and instead you can do this by exporting a CloudFormation Output from your custom resource stack and then referencing that output using an input parameter in the other stack.

With CDK

```
new CfnOutput(this, 'MyOutput', { value: 'MyValue' });
```

With CloudFormation Template

```
"Outputs": {
  "MyOutput": {
    "Value": "MyValue"
  }
}
```

Add an input parameter to the `cloudformation-template.json` of the resource you want to reference your output value in:

```
"Parameters": {
  "myInput": {
    "Type": "String",
    "Description": "A custom input"
  },
}
```

Create a `parameters.json` file that passes the output to the input parameter:

```
{
  "myInput": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": ["customResource", "Outputs.MyOutput"]
  }
}
```

Finally, reference that input in your stack:

```
"Resources": {
  "LambdaFunction": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
      "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
          "myEnvVar": {
            "Ref": "myInput"
          },
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```