# AssetParameters must have values on Amplify Push

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-amplify

I'm trying to build a simple backend with Amplify. It consist of two lambdas (lambda1 and lambda2) and a custom stack with an EventBus.

My goal is to make lambda1 trigger the eventbus rule, and the latter invoke lambda2. Both lambdas are generated by `amplify add function`.

I declare the EventBus name, the rule name and source as SSM parameters, but I'm struggling to find a way to pass these values to `lambda1`.

I found a solution here ([AWS CDK - update existing lambda environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825543/aws-cdk-update-existing-lambda-environment-variables)). The solution consists in using a CustomResource cdk class that builds a singleton lambda under the hood which will update `lambda1`'s env vars with bus name, rule name etc.

The problem is that when I try to run `amplify push` I get the following error:

```
UPDATE_FAILED  customreservationeventbridge AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Fri Jul 22 2022 16:02:25 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00) Parameters: [AssetParameters105b4f39ae68785e705640aa91919e412fcba2dd454aca53412747be8d955286S3BucketC526447A, AssetParameters105b4f39ae68785e705640aa91919e412fcba2dd454aca53412747be8d955286ArtifactHashC17A8FEC, AssetParameters105b4f39ae68785e705640aa91919e412fcba2dd454aca53412747be8d955286S3VersionKey237620B5] must have values
```

Seems like Amplify is not assigning an s3 stack to the singleton lambda or something. Honestly I could not find anything on google.

My custom stack is the following: https://pastebin.com/AfRcXBGJ

The cloudformation template generated by amplify is the following: https://pastebin.com/h6xP3d6e

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the values defined in the Amplify custom stack and pass them around from there. I could use an Amplify hook actually, but I'll need to hardcode the SSM keys in there, so it would not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by exporting a CloudFormation Output from your custom resource stack and then referencing that output using an input parameter in the other stack.

With CDK

```
new CfnOutput(this, 'MyOutput', { value: 'MyValue' });
```

With CloudFormation Template

```
"Outputs": {
  "MyOutput": {
    "Value": "MyValue"
  }
}
```

Add an input parameter to the `cloudformation-template.json` of the resource you want to reference your output value in:

```
"Parameters": {
  "myInput": {
    "Type": "String",
    "Description": "A custom input"
  },
}
```

Create a `parameters.json` file that passes the output to the input parameter:

```
{
  "myInput": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": ["customResource", "Outputs.MyOutput"]
  }
}
```

Finally, reference that input in your stack:

```
"Resources": {
  "LambdaFunction": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
      "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
          "myEnvVar": {
            "Ref": "myInput"
          },
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```